# Is there any sense in which the floor function is a "topological number"

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, topological-phase

As the title suggests, is there any sense in which the floor function can be thought of as some sort of topological number? Here by topological number I mean a topologically invariant robust quantity, like a winding number (or to give an example from physics, a Chern number). The intuition/background for this question is the following:

In a problem I'm working on, a certain number (say $n$) is essentially given by the integer number of unit wavelength waves $A(x)e^{i 2\pi x}$ that fit in a distance $d$. If I think of the phase vector of this wave, $e^{i 2\pi x}$, then $n$ is effectively the integer number of times the phase winds around the origin as $x$ goes from $0$ to $d$. However, this quantity isn't a traditional winding number, since in the complex plane the wave does not complete a closed loop in $0$ to $d$. It does feel like this is a quantity related to the winding number, and this seems to be a quantity that is robust to small perturbations (except for near the "phase" transition to the next topological number from $n$ to $n+1$).
Note that in the above description, $n=\lfloor d \rfloor$.

In this sense it seems that one could interpret the floor function as having properties that seem similar to properties of topological numbers, and there appears to be some connection to a winding number too. Is there some sense in which all of these arguments are more precise?

Comment: The floor function is definitely a topological invariant, in that it is continuous away from singular points and is quantized. If you can predict a measurable physical phenomena that depends on floor(d), then you've argued that floor(d) is an *interesting* topological invariant, like the Chern number (the Chern number predicts the Hall conductivity and edge modes, so is *interesting*!). However, you'll definitely want to understand what happens at the point where the floor function is discontinuous. Why is the phenomena robust at every $d$ except integer $d$? (cont.)

Comment: In e.g. the Chern number, you become a conductor when the Chern number isn't quantized, so your quantized Hall response breaks down. If you can predict a robust physical quantity that depends on floor(d), then something interesting must be happening when $d$ is an integer! (cont.)

Comment: OTOH, it's possible floor(d) is not an interesting invariant. For example, it might not predict a physically measurable phenomena that has quantized values. Or, it might be the case that in the relevant limit, the physical quantity is something like floor(d)/N, where $N$ is some measure of system size, and the "jumps" in floor(d) vanish in the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: So without going into too many details, in my particular problem, I do have a somewhat important (and experimentally observable!) quantity that is effectively described by the floor function of a continuous value. And in this particular context I have a somewhat deeper understanding of why the floor function arises/why there are discrete discontinuities etc. and regions of quantized values etc.

Comment: I guess my question then is: is what I have described sufficient justification for calling it a topological invariant? Or would I need some additional justification of some sort or have to show something in addition to it being described by the floor function?

Comment: It may not feel "fancy" because it's not a complicated integral of some complicated curvature, but it's quantized and observable. You might hesitate to call it a topological invariant because you don't have any underlying geometric object that you're computing an invariant of, but people have taken to using the work "topological" to mean "quantized and robust to deformations" in a lot of the literature.

Comment: It's also possible that if you look hard enough, you could find some geometric object that this floor function is secretly computing an invariant of, but that's probably overkill.